# How to remove water based wood stain splashed onto painted surface

Tags: walls, paint, staining

How do I remove the water based wood stain from my kitchen wall. I got some on my kitchen wall while I was staining my kitchen cabinets?  I tried to remove my using soap and water on a sponge. It did not work. My kitchen wall is painted with water based satin finished paint.

Comment: Any cleaning action on the wall will damage this type of wall paint. How much depends on type of action. I realize this is not hackish solution and that you didn't came here to get this answer, but I'm afraid that only solution is to paint over that wall

Answer (score 1):

The primary difficulty you are facing is that virtually all paint is somewhat porous, water based paints generally more so than alkyd (so-called *oil*) based paints. It is complicated by the fact that the stain that has been added is also water based. While there are plasiticizers in water based paints used to make them more stain resistant, these only partially prevent absorption of staining materials.

Soap and water is a good first start for most stains (after gentle blotting). The next step is usually a stronger detergent based cleanser, such as Fantastic. A test should be made on an inconspicuous area before trying any cleanser. If the test does not indicate serious compromise of the paint, proceed to attack the stain.

First put a bit of the cleanser on a paper towel or clean rag, and try rubbing the spot. If that does not work (or work well enough), try spraying directly on the stain and rubbing with the paper towel.  If some stain is being removed, keep turning the towel or rag to a clean area as you work. If this works, wipe the area with plain water when you are done.

If this does not work, you could try solvents, such as alcohol, mineral spirits, or acetone, but any of them are almost certain to compromise the finish. They also give off serious fumes and need to be handled with care.

Even the gentler detergent based cleansers may leave the paint with a different sheen from the rest of the wall. If the area is small and near trim, it may be worth dabbing a bit of matching paint over the stain. Depending on how long ago the wall was painted, it may blend and match well. If not, you may be facing a repaint of the section.

Answer (score 0):

This may be worth a shot. I have used lacquer thinner to remove a host of marks off various surfaces. I have used it to remove marks from walls finished with latex paint. The thing is it will totally remove the latex paint if you allow it. May be try this in a closet to get the hang of it first. Fold up a rag (NOT terry cloth!!) about the size of a wash cloth or a little smaller, is ok too, folding it about 4 times in each direction where it is about a 1/2" thick, uncompressed. The idea is when you fold it the last time, the 5th time, the cloth will be smooth and tight on the surface that may be about 2" by 2" on the exposed face. This is your "polishing side". Wet this side with lacquer thinner and in the closet test how it feels. It has to be wet enough to glide over the surface and not feel like it is trying to stick. Let me rephrase that, *just* wet enough. Too wet will wrinkle the paint when it saturates through. You want it just wet enough to remove the surface only. You will see the paint color on the rag.

After you feel you have the hang of it, mask off what you don't want affected, as in the trim or cabinets and give it a whirl. The paint color should not be affected if the paint job is no more than a few years old on the walls

Answer (score -1):

A damp magic eraser worked for me